# Implementing custom tabs

Tags: ios, ios6, xcode4

For an iOS 6 app I would like to implement custom tabs. I would like these tabs to look like in this app :

[image: Tabs]

As you can see, there are tabs at the almost top of the screen (tabs are : Featured/Local, Now/Rewards/Events, Rewards/Prizes)

What I would like to do is to implement similar tabs with different contents (even navigation content with table views and details views).

Actually, I would like these tabs to works exactly as the iOS tabs.

Also, like in this application, I'm already using the iOS tabs at the bottom of the screen in addition to the custom tabs I would like to add.

Can you help me and give me some directions to implement these tabs ?

I tried to have separate view controllers from which I take the root view to add it to a view in my controller that contains the tabs. However I have some issues : table views and navigation does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The controls in question are not a actually tabs, but rather a `[UISegmentedControl][1]`. Using this control will allow you simply link an IBAction to its `valueChanged` outlet in which you can define logic to changes which views are on screen based on the selected segment:

```
- (IBAction)segmentDidChange:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
            // do something
    }else{
            // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried with semgmented control but I have problems with changing the view. When the view is a navigation controler with a table view it does not work